# Java Using Saxparser results in exception thrown

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

**CODE:**

```
public void parse(byte[] payload)
{
    try
    {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler()
        {
            boolean eid = false;
            boolean msg_id = false;
            boolean date_time = false;
            boolean temp = false;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
            {
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("eid"))
                {
                    eid = true;
                }

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("msg_id"))
                {
                    msg_id = true;
                }

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("date_time"))
                {
                    date_time = true;
                }

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature"))
                {
                    temp = true;
                }
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException
            {

                if (eid)
                {
                    XMLMessagePacket.this.eid = new String(ch, start, length);
                    eid = false;
                }

                if (msg_id)
                {
                    XMLMessagePacket.this.msgId = new String(ch, start, length);
                    msg_id = false;
                }

                if (date_time)
                {
                    XMLMessagePacket.this.time =  new String(ch, start, length);
                    date_time = false;
                }

                if (temp)
                {
                    XMLMessagePacket.this.temperature.parseDouble(new String(ch, start, length));
                    temp = false;
                }

            }

        };

        saxParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload), handler);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<event>
        <eid>345345</eid>
        <msg_id>3242</msg_id>
        <date_time>11342345</date_time>
        <temperature>100</temperature>
</event>
```

**Problem:**

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I've went down that route. I've put methods in to check against that and still have the same problem

Comment: It sounds like your file is invalid - the wrong encoding, perhaps? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Are you sure there are absolutely no characters preceeding the opening `<`

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm passing a byte[] directly to the method which comes in from a udp connection. Weird thing is, new String(payload) prints it correctly

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse 100%.. Atleast not from me. Now if my java datastructures are fouling it up and slapping new characters on it, I dont know

Comment: @Mrshll187: It could easily be that you've got some invisible data (e.g. control characters) there. If you could include a hex dump in your question - or post a file online - that would be ideal.

Comment: @JonSkeet well here its is in hex 3C3F786D6C2076657273696F6E3... and so on. And 3C (the first hex) is definately an asci '<' if I'm not wrong

Comment: @Mrshll187: Looks good so far - but if you could make the whole file available (a very small sample file that demonstrates the problem) that would make it easier to help you...

Comment: @JonSkeet there were two problems. I never actually have an actual file of the xml. This xml gets created on one side (programmatically) and parsed (programmatically) on the other. The xml encoding was being set in UTF-16 and needed to be in UTF-8. Secondly, There was some crazy hidden byte order marks that hycayless mentions below.

Comment: @Mrshll187: This is why it's important to include the *actual* data. The XML document in your post didn't specify the UTF-16 part. I suspect that the UTF-16 encoding was the actual problem - if there's a UTF-8 byte order mark at the *very start of the document* it should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just something to check: a friend once fought this "bug" all night. Is it possible your file has a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning? Parsing it as a String might make it disappear. The default encoding for XML is UTF-8 (which does not require a BOM). It's just possible you're getting tripped up by something you can't see.

Comment: This was exactly what was causing it

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't *require* a byte order mark, but it's valid to have one. It sounds like the UTF-16 problem was the bigger issue here. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charencoding